# Creating subdomain within a domain on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, dns, subdomain

I am hosting a web application on a tomcat server and the current URL for example is www.mysite.com
I plan to create a Mobile version of my site and I want to be able to access it with the URL m.mysite.com

How to I create the sub-domain with my domain mysite.com?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add records to your DNS server:

- Option one: an A and/or an AAAA which points to your IPv4/IPv6 addresses
- Option two: a CNAME record to point to e.g. your www subdomain

Also your server needs to know that it should show other content on that virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should setup your DNS zone to have subdomain point at whatever IP address you have at your hosting server. Check if you may just ping your `m.mysite.com`.
2. You should ensure your webserver will answer to HTTP requests with `Host: m.mysite.com` header. This could be called `VirtualHost`.